# How to colormap from melt in R

Tags: r, colors

I've mapped colors in R before. But something isn't clicking.
Ideally, I'd like to map color names to the variable value "student", but I'm getting a length error. However, the number of students being mapped to colors is equal. Also, I've tried creating two separate color columns - as a string and as an id. The colors then end up getting labeled on the legend. Adding the manual scale color options doesn't do much.

Here is a sample of the data:

```
m3 <- structure(list(student = structure(c(7L, 11L, 9L, 2L, 8L, 4L), .Label = c("a","b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g","h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n","o", "p"), class = "factor"), colorz = structure(4:9, .Label = c("#66CC99","#9999CC", "#CC6666", "#FF0000FF", "#FF2000FF", "#FF4000FF","#FF6000FF", "#FF8000FF", "#FF9F00FF", "#FFBF00FF", "#FFDF00FF","#FFFF00FF", "green", "red"), class = "factor"), variable = structure(c(1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("pre", "c1", "c2","b1", "c3", "c4", "b2", "u1", "u2","u3", "u4", "total"), class = "factor"), value = c(3, 31,49, 88, 31, 40), col = c("#FF0000FF", "#FF2000FF", "#FF4000FF","#FF6000FF", "#FF8000FF", "#FF9F00FF")), .Names = c("student","colorz", "variable", "value", "col"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

And then graphing with: `ggplot(m3, aes(x=variable, y=value, group=student,linetype=student)) + geom_line(size=.75) + geom_point(size=2) +  xlab("test") +  ylab(paste("score")) + geom_hline(yintercept=70, linetype="dashed", size=3) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +   scale_color_identity()`

The example is much smaller than the actual data. 
Ideally, I'd like to be able to use something like:  `color.names <- setNames( c( "#FF0000FF", "#FF2000FF", "#FF4000FF", "#FF6000FF", "#FF8000FF", "#FF9F00FF","#CC6666", "#9999CC", "#66CC99",  "#FFBF00FF", "#FFDF00FF", "#FFFF00FF","green","red"), c("a","b","c", "d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n" ))`

and call the colors. I'm not sure what's messing up. It could look as if I were trying to map 12 colors to 14 values, but I've tried 14 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First just assign color to student like this, `aes(color = student)`, and then just use `scale_color_manual()` instead. Since you already named your color vector, ggplot will handle the matching based on names, unless a name isn't in the palette then that value will be dropped and not plotted:

```
ggplot(m3, aes(x=variable, y=value, group=student, linetype=student, color = student)) +
    geom_line(size=.75) + geom_point(size=2) +  xlab("test") +
    ylab(paste("score")) + geom_hline(yintercept=70, linetype="dashed", size=3) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
    scale_color_manual(values = color.names)
```

Looks like this now:
[image]